# pyspark iterate N rows from Data Frame to each execution

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, pyspark

```
def fun_1(csv):
     # returns int[] of length = Number of New Lines in String csv

def fun_2(csv): # My WorkArround to Pass one CSV Line at One Time
     return fun_1(csv)[0]
```

The Input Data Frame is df

```
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|CSVs |
+----+----+-----+
|   1|   a|2,0,1|
|   2|   b|2,0,2|
|   3|   c|2,0,3|
|   4|   a|2,0,1|
|   5|   b|2,0,2|
|   6|   c|2,0,3|
|   7|   a|2,0,1|
+----+----+-----+
```

Below is a Code Snippet which works but takes long time

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
funudf = udf(fun_2) # wish it could be fun_1
df=df.withColumn( 'pred' , funudf(sf.col('csv')))
```

`fun_1` , has a memory issue and could only handle 50000 max rows at a time. I wish to use  `funudf = udf(fun_1)` .
Hence, how can I split the PySpark DF into segments of 50000 rows , call `funudf ->fun_1` .
Output has two colunms, 'col1' from the input and 'funudf return value' .

Comment: Have you tried to repartition the data before running `udf(fun_1)`? What exactly is the memory issue you are seeing?

Comment: The call goes to another service which is compute challenging memory hungry .

Comment: If I understand correctly, `fun_1` calls this service which does something complex to the CSVs and it eats up memory. In general the easiest solution to reduce memory requirements is to repartion using a random key. It will default to 200 partitions. So you can try `df=df.repartition(800, 'some_key')` before running your UDF. Make sure to run an action like `count` before `fun_1` since `repartition` is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result of forcing PySpark to operate on fixed batches of rows by using the `groupByKey` method exposed in the RDD API. Using `groupByKey` will force PySpark to shuffle all the data for a single key to a single executor.

NOTE: for this very same reason using `groupByKey` is often discouraged because of the network cost.

Strategy:

1. Add a column that groups your data into the desired size of batches and `groupByKey`
2. Define a function that reproduces the logic of your UDF (and also returns an id for joining later on). This operates on `pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable`, the result of `groupByKey`. Apply function to your groups using `mapValues`
3. Convert the resulting RDD into a DataFrame and join back in.

Example:

```
# Synthesize DF
data = {'_id': range(9), 'group': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'vals': [2.0*i for i in range(9)]}
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))

df.show()

##
# Step - 1 Convert to rdd and groupByKey to force each group to separate executor
##
kv = df.rdd.map(lambda r: (r.group, [r._id, r.group, r.vals]))
groups = kv.groupByKey()

##
# Step 2 - Calulate function
##

# Dummy function taking 
def mult3(ditr):
    data = ditr.data
    ids = [v[0] for v in data]
    vals = [3*v[2] for v in data]
    return zip(ids, vals)

# run mult3 and flaten results
mv = groups.mapValues(mult3).map(lambda r: r[1]).flatMap(lambda r: r) # rdd[(id, val)]

## 
# Step 3 - Join results back into base DF
## 

# convert results into a DF and join back in
schema = t.StructType([t.StructField('_id', t.LongType()), t.StructField('vals_x_3', t.FloatType())])
df_vals = spark.createDataFrame(mv, schema)
joined = df.join(df_vals, '_id')

joined.show()

>>>

+---+-----+----+
|_id|group|vals|
+---+-----+----+
|  0|    a| 0.0|
|  1|    b| 2.0|
|  2|    c| 4.0|
|  3|    a| 6.0|
|  4|    b| 8.0|
|  5|    c|10.0|
|  6|    a|12.0|
|  7|    b|14.0|
|  8|    c|16.0|
+---+-----+----+

+---+-----+----+--------+
|_id|group|vals|vals_x_3|
+---+-----+----+--------+
|  0|    a| 0.0|     0.0|
|  7|    b|14.0|    42.0|
|  6|    a|12.0|    36.0|
|  5|    c|10.0|    30.0|
|  1|    b| 2.0|     6.0|
|  3|    a| 6.0|    18.0|
|  8|    c|16.0|    48.0|
|  2|    c| 4.0|    12.0|
|  4|    b| 8.0|    24.0|
+---+-----+----+--------+
```

Comment: let me try , Mean while do you have a way to use DataFrame instead of RDD

Comment: No, I am only aware of the RDD-based approach.